# how to open Hyperlinked files by default software?

Tags: notebooks

Non-*Mathematica* formats, e.g. .doc or .txt files, are directly shown in a new notebook when I click on a hyperlink pointing at these objects. But I would rather have (for example) .doc files opened using Microsoft Word. How can one create a hyperlink that opens a file in its associated application, rather than in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Please check this Q/A [.. link to a generic file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16499/125) and the docs page [SystemOpen](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SystemOpen.html)

Answer (score 5):

Slightly  modified version of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16499/125) to a related Q/A.

```
Row[{"Buttons that look like hyperlinks to open files \n ", 
Sequence @@ (Button[
   Dynamic@Style[#[[1]], 14, 
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], "HyperlinkActive", 
      "Hyperlink"]], 
   SystemOpen[$InstallationDirectory <> 
     "\\Documentation\\English\\System\\ExampleData\\" <> #[[2]]],
    Appearance -> None] & /@
 {{"Spikey   ", "spikey2.png"},
  {"Calendar   ", "calendar.ics"},
  {"A pdf file   ", "mathematica.pdf"}}),
  " \nusing ", Hyperlink["SystemOpen", "paclet:ref/SystemOpen"], "."}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can open with Word like this:

```
file = "http://backend.ewock.com/ewockhome/images/word8.doc";

Run["start winword \"" <> file <> "\""];
```

And you could make a hyperlink like this:

```
Row[{Style["Demo\[ThinSpace]", FontFamily -> "Arial"],
 Button[Style["test doc", Blue, FontFamily -> "Arial"],
  Run["start winword \"" <> file <> "\""], Appearance -> "Frameless"],
 Style["\[ThinSpace]hyperlink", FontFamily -> "Arial"]}]
```

[image]