# How insert hyperlink to file with relative path?

Tags: notebooks, button, hyperlink

Into a text cell of my current (previously saved) notebook, I want to place a hyperlink to a particular file `target.html` in a particular subdirectory `subdir` of the notebook's directory.

I don't see a way to do this directly using the menu item Insert > Hyperlink.

However, if I edit the cell as an expression, I can form the following:

```
Cell[TextData[{
   "Look at this ",
   ButtonBox["page", BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
      ButtonData:>{
         URL[
              StringJoin["file://", 
                  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "subdir/target.html"}]
                  ]
            ], 
         None}],"..."
     }], "Text"]
```

(Above, I've hand-formatted the display to correctly display the structure, I hope.)

However, once I convert that expression back into a text cell in the notebook and click the hyperlink, the indicated file does not open in the default browser.

What's wrong and how should it be fixed?

Comment: Follow those steps and put whatever you want to the Hyperlink. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37518/5478

Comment: related q/a: [how to open Hyperlinked files by default software?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17873/125)

Comment: @Kuba:I presume you refer to your own answer in the post cited. For argument "testlink", I use `"file://"<>FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"subdir/target.html"}]`. But when I click the resulting hyperlink, I get error "The front end failed to execute the command file File:///Users/murray/dir/subdir/target.html", where dir is the notebook's directory.

Comment: @murray What about `SystemOpen @ FileNameJoin[...` only? I'm not quite sure where is this `file://` part from and whether it should work or not.

Comment: I think I've traced the source of the difficulty to the notebook's directory name have a space within it. if I remove that space, then the method works, namely, to evaluate in-line a `Hyperlink["test","file:///"<>FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"subdir/target.html"}]]`. (And this has nothing to do with the target file being in a subdirectory of the notebook's directory.) The issue is that the expression generates a link with an embedded space. How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Rule (->)` instead of  `RuleDelayed (:>)`

```
Cell[TextData[{
   "Look at this ",
   ButtonBox["page", BaseStyle->"Hyperlink",
      ButtonData->{
         URL[StringJoin["file://", 
                  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "subdir/target.html"}]
                  ]
            ], 
         None}],"..."
     }], "Text"] //CellPrint
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Original post:

**Using `Button`:**

```
Row[{Style["Look at this ", "Panel", 16], 
  Button[Dynamic@Style["page", 16, If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
         "HyperlinkActive", "Hyperlink"]], 
   SystemOpen[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "subdir/target.html"}]], 
   Appearance -> None], " ..."}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

**Using `Hyperlink`:**

```
Row[{Style["Look at this ", "Panel", 16], 
  Hyperlink[Style["page", FontFamily->"Panel", 14], 
   "file://" <> FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "subdir/target.html"}]], 
  " ..."}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Neither of those input cells produce an output that is, or is within a `Text` cell. I need the hyperlink within an existing `Text` cell (and, in fact, one that could have a fair amount of text already in it).

Comment: @murray, ah i see. I will update in a moment.

Comment: I cannot effectively create a `Cell` expression and apply `CellPrint` to it: I already have the text cell and need to add a hyperlink to it.

Comment: @murray, i used `CellPrint` just to show how the cell will look like when you uncheck the `Show Expression`  in the `Cell` menu. The only change you need to make in your code is to change `ButtonData:>...` to ButtonData->...`.